# How to change default font size in TinyMCETextField when using TinyMCEEditor Wrapper in Vaadin 7 project?

Tags: java, tinymce, wrapper, vaadin7, rich-text-editor

Title says it all. I found that you have to edit some TinyMCEEditor css-file but how and where to do that in a Vaadin 7 project? With all its theme and style css-structures.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code....

```
      <div role="treeitem" hidefocus="true" style="font-size: 0pt; position: absolute; outline: 0px none; z-index: -1;" tabindex="0">
        <input style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;" tabindex="-1" type="text" />
```

Comment: See my friend, you want to change the default font size right,,,, then just see in my code <div> is having style= font-size: 0pt , so you can can change it..ok

Comment: That's helpful. And do you know where to place that css in a Vaadin 7 project?